# Swift trailingAnchorが効かない

Tags: swift, ios

下記コードにおいて、`trailingAnchor`が全く効きません。

最低限のテストとして、ボタンを一つにして横方向の制約`leadingAnchor`と`trailingAnchor`の二つを設定しても、さらには`trailingAnchor`だけを設定しても、`trailingAnchor`の右端との関係は無視され、ボタンは左寄りにしか表示されません。

`trailingAnchor`が効いていないためと思いますが、画面を回転させても横幅は変わりませんが、縦方向はオートレイアウトが効き縦幅は制約通り変化します。

間違っている点があればご指摘いただけないでしょうか。
また、改善策をご教授いただければ幸いです。

テスト環境
・Xcode8.3.2
・iOS10.3.3（iPadMini4実機）

```
    @IBOutlet var buttons:[UIButton] = []

    ...中略...

    //ボタンの表示
    func buttonIndicate(){

        for roop in 0...11 {
            //ボタンの横位置を決める
            let button:UIButton = UIButton()
            //表示されるテキスト
            button.setTitle(String(roop), for: .normal)
            //テキストの色
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            //バックグラウンドカラー
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            //タグ番号
            button.tag = roop
            button.restorationIdentifier = String(roop)
            //このあと追加する制約とコンフリクトさせないため
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            buttons.append(button)

        }

        let keyColum = 11

        //viewに追加して制約を設定
        for roop in 0...11{
            self.view.addSubview(buttons[roop])
            //X方向の制約
            if roop == 0 {
                //最初のボタンと左端の関係
                self.buttons[roop].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 1).isActive = true
            } else {
                //前のボタンとの関係
                self.buttons[roop].leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttons[roop - 1].trailingAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
            }
            //幅の制約　前のボタンと同じ幅
            if roop != 0{
                self.buttons[roop].widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.buttons[roop - 1].widthAnchor).isActive = true
            }
            //一番右のボタンと右端の関係 ここが全く効いていない
            if roop == keyColum{
                self.buttons[roop].trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -1)
            }
            //Y方向の制約
            //topとの関係
            self.buttons[roop].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            //bottumとの関係
            self.buttons[roop].bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: 「`trailingAnchor`が効いていない」のではなく、「`trailingAnchor`を設定するコードが実行されていない」のではないですか?

Comment: `keyColum = roop.count`だと12になりますね。コードの転記ミスですので`keyColum = 11`と書き換えました。`if roop == keyColum`の中に'print("Passed",ropp)'を記述して、意図した通りroop=11の時のみ`trailingAnchor`コードが実行（？）されていることは確認しております。確認方法が間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ケアレスミスでした。
`isActive = true`が抜けていました。
申し訳ございませんでした。